# Testing index changes in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch index that contains a few million documents. The script that builds the index takes a few hours to go from start to finish. This makes it pretty impractical for testing out code changes against production database data.

On production, I have a million items. Each one is indexed in the server. I find out that my code incorrectly populates one of the fields. In my local dev environment using a much smaller set of test data, my code seems to have resolved the problem. However, past experience suggests that my users do crazy things, and that my test data rarely covers every single case. (There are complicated permissions and other things that interact with each other to determine a simple Boolean value for one field, and sometimes those really complicated fields go in directions I hadn't anticipated in the test data.)

In order to minimize screwing up my production index, I want to run my updated elasticsearch indexing code against the production database to make sure that it works for all users. Specifically, I just want to run it against a handful of user's data that I know are having problems. I can't simply just export this data to my local dev environment, because the data is so complex. Therein lies the problem.

I want to avoid having to rebuild a separate index every time I want to test a change. (Obviously, if I build a separate index and then don't update it regularly, then the next time I test will have outdated data.)

Thoughts? Ideas? Suggestions? Bad jokes? Am I just gonna have to rebuild an index every time? Are there any shortcuts I can take to minimize the time I sit around waiting for the index to complete?

Comment: Few hours for few million records sounds a lot. Can you be specific? i guess people can index a million in 10-15 mins.

Comment: Sure. It's not the indexing that takes a long time, it's the calculations for generating the index. For instance, generating the data to index one document might take up to 2 or 3 seconds (most will be well under 0.001s, though), since there are complex calculations involved to return a simple Boolean value (say, permissions, etc). It's not the indexing itself that takes a long time, it's the calculation for the document that is being indexed. However, it's not possible to speed this up any further (at least for now).

Comment: if 1% of 1 million documents takes 2s each, and the rest take 0.001s each, then the entire process might still take 5 hours to finish. And there are actually a few million documents in the index...

Comment: is it possible to calculate documents and store it in database so that the indexing process just reads from it? you can have multiple threads running for "preparing" the documents and one or two threads indexing it, possible?

Comment: That's not a bad idea. My big concern is the cost of storing that data (from both time and storage standpoints), but I'll test it out and see if it helps.

Comment: calculate, store, index and delete every N days to keep the sizes less.

Comment: Isn't it the index available for search while it keeps being indexed? See also http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-refresh.html . If you do not require all your documents for testing, then you can start using it before it finished indexing. If not, you have to wait :-)